# Convert applescript to applescript studio

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc, applescript-studio

This is my first time here. Anyway I have a question.

I just decided to try using Applescript studio, but currently I have trouble converting my script and linking actions to the GUI. I will provide more info if needed, but I just need to convert an applescript for use in Applescript studio. Is there any specific code I need to inject or something? Thanks.

Running on Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard, Xcode 4.2

Comment: Are you really talking about AppleScript Studio?  AS Studio is deprecated as of Snow Leopard - the new framework is AppleScriptObjC.

Comment: Sorry, I meant AppleScriptObjC, I thought they were both the same. I'm using a Cocoa-Applescript template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AppleScriptObjC in Xcode, the Interface Editor will use any handler with the right definition as an action method.  An action handler takes a single parameter, which means that it has a single trailing underscore in the name - see the [AppleScriptObjC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/_index.html).

Once a handler has been declared, it will show up in the Interface Editor and can be connected by dragging from the Connections Inspector to the desired UI object, or by right-clicking on a UI object and dragging from the popup to the desired script class.

Example projects are a bit scarce, but a couple of resources to bring you up to speed are the introductory [tutorials at MacScripter.net](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=30274), and Shane Stanley's excellent [AppleScriptObjC Explored](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/) ebook.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the MacScripter tutorials! They're really helpful. :)